# Распаковывание переменных шаблона

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Всем привет! Уже немало времени пытаюсь понять, как получить доступ к списку переменных шаблонов. Необходимо для каждого передаваемого параметра, если он является rvalue, сделать кое-какие преобразования и результат поместить в вектор. Но этот код вызывает не

```
vec.push_back(T&&)
```

, а его lvalue аналог

```
vec.push_back(const T&)
```

Вот код самой функции:

```
template <typename T>
template <typename... Args>
void Func(std::vector<T>& vec, Args&&... args) {
    for(auto&& x : { std::forward<Args>(args)...} ) {
        /* какие-то манипуляции с x */
        vec.push_back(std::move(x));
    }
}
```

Подскажите, как вызывать метод с rvalue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С `std::initializer_list` проблема в том, что в нем элементы всегда константные. Перемещать из него не получится.

Я бы сделал что-то вроде:

```
template <typename T, typename ...P>
void Func(std::vector<T> &vec, P &&... params)
{
    auto lambda = [&](auto &&x)
    {
        /* какие-то манипуляции с x */
        vec.push_back(decltype(x)(x));
    };

    (lambda(std::forward<P>(params)), ...);
}
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, это помогло в моем случае. А возможно ли обойтись без использования развертывания (...)? Например, с помощью какого-нибудь цикла?

Comment: @MDefault А зачем? Компилятор старый и не умеет в fold expressions?

Comment: Да, используется версия до c++14. Да  и просто из любопытства, как можно еще реальзовать такое.

Comment: @MDefault Тогда примерно вот так: `int dummy[] = {0, (lambda(std::forward<P>(params)), 0)...}; (void)dummy;`